# What does expressing ‘velocity’ as a function of $(x,y)$ mean?

Tags: kinematics, velocity, vectors

[image]

This is a question from my textbook. We have been given an equation of trajectory (equation of an ellipse), and the question wants me to express the velocity vectorially as a function of (x,y). 
I understood the solution, what I don’t understand is : What does expressing velocity ‘vectorially’ as a function of (x,y) mean?

The answer that we get (circled expression) has three variables (x,y & v), not just (x,y).

I just don’t know how to understand this expression of velocity vectorially as a function of (x,y). Maybe, because I’ve never seen it before. (I’m still at school).

Please help me understand it.

Comment: Please, do not post pictures. Type the question instead (and using MathJax for formulae).  There are many reasons, including facilitation for algorithms and helping users whose device doesn't display them well. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry. Actually I’m not familiar with MathJax, typing the whole thing would have taken a very long time. Also, I thought attaching the pic would make my question clearer. I understand I’m supposed to use MathJax. I tried learning it, just found it very complicated

Comment: Not really, It's about writing them in between of dollar symbols, and laTex commands inside. Like this: `$E_k=\frac{1}{2} m v^2$` See here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: taking the time to type it in MathJax will give you additional time to think about your question... which is always good.

Comment: You should consider $v$ to be a given value that does not change.  Yes, it is a variable that represents a number that can change, but in the context of the question it is just a stand-in for a specific number.

Comment: @garyp If $x$ and $y$ change, it means $v_x$ and $v_y$ would change. And if $v_x$ and $v_y$ can change, it means $v$ can change as a result. How is $v$ a constant value then?

Comment: $v_x$ and $v_y$ can change in such a way that the modulsu is constant. IF $v_x$ increases, $v_y$ decreases in such a way that $\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}=constant$

Comment: Indeed, you are told that the modulus stays constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple. The velocity vector is not constant, it is changing during the movement. If the velocity did not change, the movement would be in straight line and uniform, but it is an ellipse, so $\vec{v}$ must change, neccesarily.

These changes are usually written in terms of time. You are probably used to $v(t)$, like for example $v=v_0+at$.

But, as we know the equation of the trajectory, we know the position for any value of $t$. So there is a relation between $t$ and position.

Since you know that relation, writing $v$ in terms of time or in terms or position is **equivalent**.

---

### Details.

To be precise, this can only be done in some cases.

Now, realize that this ellipse is a closed-path. This can be a cyclic movement. That's what we call a periodic motion.

It could be non-periodic. For example, if the particle gained speed every time, so that each lap is faster, it would not be periodic, because each lap would be different than the previous one. BUT, in this case, the movement is periodic. Why? Because it says it has constant speed.

And that's the key. See. If the movement is periodic, you can be sure that all laps are the same. So the velocity vector is changing in time, but it keeps repating its values every period.

When this happens, it makes more sense to write $v$ in terms of position. And what it means is that every time the particle is located at one point (position), it has a ceratin velocity. That velocity is given by the equations of movement.

> In short, the idea is that we assume that the particle acquires that velocity when it passes through that point.

For example, the velocity vector $(v, 0)$ is the one at the lowest point of the ellipse.

Every time the particle passes through that point (position corresponding to an angle of 270 degrees), the velocity vector is that one, $(v, 0)$. It cannot be any other because otherwise it wouldn't be an ellipse.

And this will happen at a time $t_0$, because the position at $t=t_0$ is that one.

But it wll happen more times: for $t_0$, $_0+T$, $t_00+2T$, and so on.

Of course this was just an easy example of point, but it is valid for any point you choose. Every point has an associated velocity vector, which will be different of course.

So there are two ideas.

- $\vec{v}(t)$ and $\vec{v}(x,y)$ give us the same information, because we know the relation ebtween time and position.
- This way of expressing velocity is more typcial of periodic movements, in which we don't care of $T$ as much, because we already know it's periodic. Rather, we care about what is the velocity the particle has in each position.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for such a thorough explanation. Finally it makes sense to me. Yeah, I’ve mostly been dealing with simpler expressions, this one was completely new to me. Thanks again for the beautiful explanation

Comment: I'm glad it seemed beatiful to you. I thought it was being messy, but I'm having a hard time writing right now haha.

Comment: It was indeed beautiful. You explained everything so nicely, bit by bit. I had just assumed that I wouldn’t be able to understand this, until I covered a good portion of my physics syllabus. But decided to post it anyway, hoping I might get some intuition about it. You explained it so nicely! :) Thanks a lot

Comment: If you like this answer, do the right thing and accept it!

Comment: How do I accept it?

Comment: I have another question, kinda related. Can we derive the position-time relation of the particle if (and only if) its equation of trajectory is given to us? If yes, how? I'm not sure if I should create a separate thread for this question. If I am supposed to ask this question in another post, please let me know. I will.

Comment: @πtimese Yes, you should post a separate question, no matter if it is related. It is another question, independent of this one. In this site we don't like to overload threads, which is logic too.